# Mysql Calculate time difference between timestamps in same field containing text?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Is it possible to calculate the time difference from a timestamp in the same field containing text? Here are my table date:

```
 ID, FIELD1, totalTime
 '1', '2018-06-03 09h56##firstname.lastname##2018-06-03 16h45##firstname.lastname', ''
 '2', '2018-02-06 17h24##firstname.lastname##2018-02-06 21h03##firstname.lastname', ''
 '3', '2018-01-01 02h23##firstname.lastname##2018-01-01 17h24##firstname.lastname', ''
```

So I would need to calculate the time for each line: EX: (2018-02-03 16h45) - (2018-02-03 09h56)

My SQL knowledge isn't bad, but I can't figure out how I'd go about doing such a thing on the same field.

Thanks,

Elizabeth

Comment: Firstly, very poor way of storing data. They should have been in separate columns. Now if you cannot change the way data is stored; you will need to first use string functions (like substring etc) to extract the two datetime strings separately. Use str_to_date function to convert it to MySQL datetime format, and then do a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the workhorse functions `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `STR_TO_DATE`. The `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function can calculate a difference between DATETIME values.

(I'm going to skip over the discussion about not storing multiple datetime and strings in one big text column. Suffice it to say that it's a SQL anti-pattern, and bad practice.)

String processing in SQL is inelegant (the SQL gets ugly real fast), but we can handle some rudimentary, well defined, operations.

Because we have regular delimiters `##` in the column values, if we have that as a guarantee, we can make use of `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function to extract portions between those delimiters.

As a demonstration:

```
SELECT -- extract string parts
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.field1,'##',1)                                                          AS d1_str
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.field1,'##',3),'##',-1)                                 AS d2_str

       -- convert stringparts to DATETIME
     , STR_TO_DATE( SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.field1,'##',1)                          ,'%Y-%m-%d %Hh%i') AS d1_dt
     , STR_TO_DATE( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.field1,'##',3),'##',-1) ,'%Y-%m-%d %Hh%i') AS d2_dt

       -- calculate time difference (in minutes) of the DATETIME
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE
                    , STR_TO_DATE( SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.field1,'##',1) , '%Y-%m-%d %Hh%i') 
                    , STR_TO_DATE( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.field1,'##',3),'##',-1) , '%Y-%m-%d %Hh%i') 
       ) AS diff_minutes

  FROM ( SELECT  '1'+0 AS id, '2018-06-03 09h56##firstname.lastname##2018-06-03 16h45##firstname.lastname' AS field1
          UNION ALL SELECT '2'+0, '2018-02-06 17h24##firstname.lastname##2018-02-06 21h03##firstname.lastname'
          UNION ALL SELECT '3'+0, '2018-01-01 02h23##firstname.lastname##2018-01-01 17h24##firstname.lastname'
       ) t
```

returns:

```
d1_str            d2_str            d1_dt                d2_dt                diff_minutes
----------------  ----------------  -------------------  -------------------  ------------
2018-06-03 09h56  2018-06-03 16h45  2018-06-03 09:56:00  2018-06-03 16:45:00           409
2018-02-06 17h24  2018-02-06 21h03  2018-02-06 17:24:00  2018-02-06 21:03:00           219
2018-01-01 02h23  2018-01-01 17h24  2018-01-01 02:23:00  2018-01-01 17:24:00           901
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Those sql expressions get real ugly real fast. heaven help the poor soul that has to come behind and decipher it. Also, those sql expressions work only because of the regular pattern of the delimiters, the guaranteed format for the datetime strings, etc. Overall, the solution seems jury-rigged.